# React slow rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to render a table with 500 rows.
It's very slow.
By clicking on a checkbox, I fire select action, and update my state that's way, the browser becomes very slow for a 2 seconds, and then the checkbox is applied:

```
const selected = !state.items[action.selected].selected;
return {
            ...state,
            items: {
                ...state.items,
                [action.selected]: {
                    ...state.items[action.selected],
                    selected: selected,
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, the rendering itself is very slow.
I have a 'loading...' message when I fetch the data, and by getting the result, the loading is disappears, and I wait about 4 seconds in order for the data to be displayed.

How can I solve it?

Comment: impossible to answer with the given information.

Comment: Have you looked into using selectors (possibly by using [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#motivation-for-memoized-selectors))? The example in that link looks like the same kind of thing you're trying to accomplish.